# Default ID with Korma and Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, compojure, korma

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS art_pieces
(
  -- Art Data
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  description TEXT,
  price INT NULL,

  -- Relations
  artists_id INT NULL

);

--;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artists
(
  -- Art Data
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

This is the corresponding art-piece entity:

```
(defentity art-pieces
  (table :art_pieces)
  (entity-fields
    :id
    :title
    :description
    :price
    :artists_id)
  (belongs-to artists))
```

I'm wondering why the following returns `PSQLException ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`:

```
(create-piece {:title "The Silence of the Lambda" 
               :description "Something something java beans and a nice chianti" 
               :price 5000})
```

Shouldn't the `ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` field populate automatically? Is this something to do with Korma's interaction with PSQL?

Comment: What should ID be automatically set to? I usually use a trigger that sets it to a UUID

Comment: I believe in Postgres SERIAL is supposed to increment to the next int available. in psql `insert into art_pieces VALUES (default, 'foo', 'bar', 5, null);` successfully creates a new one and increments the ID. I just checked the korma function and it evaluates to `INSERT INTO "art_pieces" ("description", "id", "price", "title") VALUES (?, NULL, ?, ?) ....`

Comment: What's the definition for the `create-piece` function?

Comment: Could have sworn I took ID out of the definition explicitly for this reason but I guess it was still there. The following works, but if it has id in there which gets filled as nil it will error.

    (defn create-piece [piece]
      (insert art-pieces
              (values {
                        :title (:title piece)
                        :description (:description piece)
                        :price (:price piece)})))

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO "art_pieces" ("description", "id", "price", "title") VALUES (?, NULL, ?, ?)
```

The problem here is that you try to insert `NULL` value into `id` column. Default value is inserted only if you omit the column or use `DEFAULT` keyword (instead of `NULL`).

> To insert the next value of the sequence into the serial column, specify that the serial column should be assigned its default value. This can be done either by excluding the column from the list of columns in the INSERT statement, or through the use of the DEFAULT key word

[PostgreSQL Serial Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

So you have to change the query to:

```
INSERT INTO "art_pieces" ("description", "id", "price", "title") VALUES (?, DEFAULT, ?, ?)
-- or
INSERT INTO "art_pieces" ("description", "price", "title") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

---

Another workaround (in case you don't have permissions to change the query) would be to add a `trigger` function that will replace `NULL` value in `id` column automatically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tf_art_pieces_bi() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    -- if insert NULL value into "id" column
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND new.id IS NULL THEN
        -- set "id" to the next sequence value
        new.id = nextval('art_pieces_id_seq');
    END IF;
    RETURN new; 
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER art_pieces_bi
BEFORE INSERT
ON art_pieces
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tf_art_pieces_bi();
```